# How to sync original bpm of an mp3 file to the bpm of my drum module?

Tags: drums, recording, tempo

I start by creating a drum loop or a percussion loop in Acoustica Mixcraft at a specified bpm. I turn into an mp3 file, store it on a usb, connect the usb to my Roland TD-30 Module and play it as a song. I would like to play the drums along with the percussion loop using the internal click, set at the very same bpm. The internal bpm is ALMOST in synch with the tempo of the mp3 file but unfortunately not entirely. At the end of the song you start to hear that they are out of synch. It isn't much, but enough to hear the difference, and hence it will not work. I can adjust the speed of the song (the mp3 file) but only in percentage units and one single percentage unit would be too much. How could this be solved?

Comment: can you not set the bpm when you start creating the loop, then match the same bpm on the click track by entering it?

Comment: Is the song in the mp3 at a constant tempo? If it's not, you'll need to adjust it to be constant using something like Live's warp.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wanted to avoid it, but it sounds like any solution may be far more trouble than its worth, so just go with a click on the actual loop.

But if you definitely want it in sync with the internal click I would try these out...

- Use a midi out from your drums, set its clock to master. Midi in to your DAW, set clock to external. Set the bpm you want on your drums and then make the tracks using the drums clock as a control
- Midi cable from your computer to your drums, headphones into your drums, play the midi sequence in your DAW and you can hear it on your drums. Then export a midi file not a song

Comment: If there is some reason you cannot connect your DAW to your TD-30, and you are restricted/committed to plugging in a USB drive with an audio file on it, perhaps try a different (lossless) encoding like .wav.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: record your MP3 twice, once with a click, once without. Use the version with a click, instead of the drum module's internal click.

More technical solution: synchronise your drum module's tempo with your DAW using MIDI.